# Netsuite Expression for Formula (Date) Field

Tags: netsuite

I am new to the NetSuite expressions and I am using the following formula in a Opportunity Saved Search result but it is returning an Invalid Expression.

I am trying to display the Systems Note Date when an Opportunity Status was changed to 'Suspect'.

CASE WHEN {systemnotes.field} IN {entitystatus} END CASE WHEN {systemnotes.newvalue}=Suspect THEN {systemnotes.date}  END

Answer (score 0):

In a single expression, there should only be one CASE and one END and then you can have several WHEN/THEN statements.

Your formula should be more like this:
CASE WHEN  {systemnotes.field} = 'Entity Status' AND {systemnotes.newvalue}='Suspect' THEN {systemnotes.date} END

This is assuming you have Suspect as a value for this, but this should be correct